# NetworkX -- nx.draw() appears to create infinite loop

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to create a network representation of a bunch of twitter accounts using data I've collected over the past few months. I'm using a dictionary of dictionaries to represent an adjacency matrix with weighted, directional connections between the accounts, where the values in the inner dictionary are these numerical weights. The problem I keep running into, however, comes when I run `nx.draw()` on my dataset.

```
def makeDiGraph(adjacencyMatrix = None):
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    for i in adjacencyMatrix:
        for j in adjacencyMatrix[i]:
            if adjacencyMatrix[i][j] > 0:
                G.add_edge(i, j)
    nx.draw(G)
    plt.show()
```

When I run this code using my dict of dicts, I get no errors, but instead I get what appears to be some kind of infinite loop in my program. Since the loop appears to be happening within the `nx.draw()` function (as determined by my usage of print statements to find where control is stopping), I can't do much in the way of debugging to figure out where exactly the issue is. occurring. I've experimented with adding and removing the following line after I instantiate the `DiGraph()` object in order to place the nodes before I implement the edges, but I am still running into the same problem.

```
for i in adjacencyMatrix:
    G.add_node(i)
```

I imagine the problem is occurring somewhere in the way that I am placing the edges, but I am not sure what is wrong with my code.

Here is an example subset of my data:

```
{'@RepFinkenauer': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepLindaSanchez': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepKatieHill': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepTimBurchett': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@SenBooker': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepSylviaGarcia': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepDelBene': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@amprog': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepMcNerney': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}, '@RepJuanVargas': {'@RepFinkenauer': 0, '@RepLindaSanchez': 11, '@RepKatieHill': 0, '@RepTimBurchett': 0, '@SenBooker': 13, '@RepSylviaGarcia': 15, '@RepDelBene': 6, '@amprog': 4, '@RepMcNerney': 0, '@RepJuanVargas': 18}}
```

It looks like the problem is the size of the dataset, as I don't run into the same issue when I run the code on this smaller dataset (1/50th the size of the real dataset).

Comment: What makes you think it's in an infinite loop? Is it just taking a long time? How many nodes / edges are in your graph? If you reduce the number of nodes to < 100 does it draw?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example that can be reproduced??

Comment: The issue is probably that the network is very large and it's taking too long to draw.  I doubt very much that there is an infinite loop here.

Comment: on second look, it isn't an infinite loop! the problem, however, is that it takes a whole lot of time to produce a very crowded canvas that then becomes unresponsive and causes the 'python' application to crash. not sure if i should be using a different draw function